Custom TextField Deprecated Animation Replacement
Found a cool custom String field modifier that changes the placeholder position & size based on whether the field is empty.  However it uses the deprecated .animation and wants that replaced.
The code that has animation that works correctly but with deprecated call...
struct StringInputField: View {
    var fieldTitle: String
    @Binding var fieldText: String
    
    init(_ fieldTitle: String, fieldText: Binding<String>) {
        self.fieldTitle = fieldTitle
        self._fieldText = fieldText
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(fieldTitle)
                .foregroundColor(fieldText.isEmpty ? Color(.placeholderText) : .accentColor)
                .offset(y: fieldText.isEmpty ? 0 : -25)
                .scaleEffect(fieldText.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.8, anchor: .leading)
            TextField("", text: $fieldText)
        }
        .padding(.top, 15)
        .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
}

Its called from the editing form view...
       Form {
            Section("General Setup") {
                StringInputField("League Name", fieldText: $league.name)

                ...
                ...

            }
            
            Section("Scoring Details") {
                IntInputField(fieldTitle: "Bowlers On A Team", fieldInt: $league.bowlersPerTeam)
                
                ...
                ...
                
            }
        }
        .animation(.smooth(duration: 5), value: league.type)
        .navigationTitle(league.name.isEmpty ? "Add Your League" : "Editing League Information")

So using the deprecated version in StringInputField, the animation works perfectly.  But if I use what I think is the more proper version, it just jumps...
.animation(.easeInOut, value: fieldText.isEmpty)

Why would it now jump?  Am I calling it wrong?  In the editing form there is an animation there which I haven't touched as it works fine.  It just shows a couple extra fields based on a segmented control tapped.  So I don't think it is the problem but maybe?
Thanks...
Scott

What do you mean by "it just jumps"? What jumps? How and when does it "jump"? The animation works great for me on iOS 17.4.

The code above that uses .animation(.easeInOut)  works smoothly but I get the following warning in Xcode: "'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead."  So I assume that I need to change the implementation to something like .animation(.smooth, value: fieldText.isEmpty) or .animation(.easeInOut, value: fieldText.isEmpty) .  Using one of the latter 2 choices, the Placeholder text disappears from the field and instantly appears higher and shrunk.  So right location but no animation to get it there.  That was the jump I referred to.

I cannot reproduce that on iOS 17.4. What version are you running?

Still new at this.  My minimum deployment is iOS17.2 and running it on iPad Pro Sim 17.2.  Which animation code are you using that works?  Do you get the Xcode warning if you just use .animation(.easeInOut).   Also note in the editing view Form, I have an animation attached there that lets a couple textfields be shown depending on a segmented control.  I don't think that should be interfering since I can use the deprecated code and all works fine.

I mean the code with value: of course. Does the issue still occur if you remove the animation on the Form?

YUP.  I removed the animation on the Form and TextField animations still the same.  Although obviously now as I tap the segmented control, my fields "pop" on the screen and are no longer animated smoothly.  I am using Xcode 15.2 and looks like my sims are at 17.2

OK, I moved .animation(.easeInOut, value: fieldText.isEmpty) from the ZStack to the Text(fieldTitle) right after .scaleEffect... and it now works correctly.  Strange why it wouldn't fire attached to ZStack.  The deprecated one did.  Oh well. all is good now...
